# Does eating charred meat cause cancer?

Tags: nutrition, cancer, meat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does burning your food increase your risk of getting cancer?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4714/does-burning-your-food-increase-your-risk-of-getting-cancer)

I've been told that I shouldn't eat charred meat (and at least sweep the charring off of a barbequeued sausage), because it can cause cancer.  I've had a look at what I can find on the subject, and it seems a little open to interpretation to me (one study I looked at could equally have been interpreted that a genetic predisposition to enjoying well-cooked meat increases the probability of cancer.)

Is there any hard science on the subject?

Comment: @Oddthinking It's a fair cop.

Comment: :-) I hope this isn't seen as "being caught", but as helpful, because there is already an accepted answer there (admittedly from me, which is why I knew the duplicate existed...)

Comment: @Oddthinking Not at all - I did look at the suggested questions list, but I don't think it came up because I put "charred" instead of "burned".

Comment: This terminologyy confusion sounds like a good reason to keep this question and NOT delete it, so it's searchable. (this was a note to anyone considering hitting "delete" link)