# Does grilled meat cause cancer?

Tags: nutrition, cancer, meat

On a business trip to China, I ate a lot of wonderful food.  Towards the end of the second week, I was craving BBQ, a hamburger, anything...  I asked our interpreter if there were any such places around (Shenzhen) that had this sort of food.  She looked at me with horror.  I mean, not just a shocked look, but like I was pulling the curtain open while she was in the shower and I had a knife in my hand.  She told me that "they" believe that grilled meat (that with char marks) causes cancer.

Does charred meat cause cancer?  Are there any studies?

Comment: Thnx Flimzy, I didn't see it as I was searching for grilling specifically

Comment: @Flimzy I'm not sure this is a duplicate, as far as I remember there are some specific carcinogens created when the fat is burnt on the coals in a BBQ. So this question might be different enough.

Comment: @Fabian: Then it would be a duplicate of [this one](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/7042/4020), which was closed as a duplicate of the other.